# Change the value of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html page I'm having one div element as subbutton. In javascript I'm appending button to this div element.

```
$.each(responseObj.me, function (i, me) {
    $('#subbutton').append('<input type="button" value=subscribe id="subscribe" background-color="green" onclick="">'+'</input>');
    var subscribe=check();

    function check()
    {       
        if(responseObj.me[i].isSubscribed==="false")
            {
            document.getElementById("subscribe").value="I Trust";

            $('#subbutton').click(function() {
                sub(text);
                document.getElementById("subscribe").value="Trusted";
            });           
        }       
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("subscribe").value="Trusted";

            $('#subbutton').click(function() {  
            unsub(text);
            document.getElementById("subscribe").value="I Trust";             
        });          
    }           
}
```

But the problem is when I click on the button first time, it's able to subscribe if it's not subscribed and able to unsubscribe if it's already subscribed. But if again I want to subscribe who is unsubscribed then it's not unsubscribed.sub(text) is a function used to subscribe person and unsub(text) is a function to unsubscribe person.

Comment: Please create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for it so that it would be easier to debug

Comment: Start with learning basic HTML first, *then*  javascript !

Comment: What's `responseObj`..? please add the relevant code and info to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @adeneo..if u cant help then u dont have any rights to tell anyone about what to learn and what to not.this site is helping not to comment about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use,

```
$(document).on("click",".subscribe",function(){
//your code here
});
```

i created a jsfiddle. just check it out whether that is your aim

http://jsfiddle.net/2dAf9/

Answer (score 0):

is you are calling check method more than one time??
then instead of using $('#subbutton').click() you have to use $('#subbutton').unbind("click").bind("click",function(){});
because it will not clear the click event it first initialized. it will call both funcitons.
try this way

Comment: hw many button do you want? because you are appending button element in loop. thats why im asking

Comment: i want only one button whose value changes between i trust and trusted..depending upon function call.